# MVC2 Json result - include cookies?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, cookies

Can you return cookies when returning an MVC2 Json result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - Not via the json result but you can simply add in your same controller method Response.Cookies.Add() and they will be added.

**Note:** that in the an Async action you will need to set the response cookie in the completed method.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult GetCookies()
 {
    var cookies = from c in Request.Cookies.AllKeys
             select new {Key = c, Value = Request.Cookies[c].Value};
    return this.Json(cookies);
 }
```